# Open details of a single row in a datatable in a new page

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I have a datatable from database and I would like details of one of the rows appear in a new table when I click on the **"OPEN"** button as in the screenshot below.[image]

When I click on the OPEN button I get "No records found " as in the next screenshot below[image]
Here is part of the **index.xhtml**

//

APP WEB

```
                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{transaction.onRowEdit}" update=":form1:messages" />  
                    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{transaction.onRowCancel}" update=":form1:messages" /> 

                    <p:column headerText="Reference">
                        <p:commandLink value="#{c.reference}" action="/faces/global/SingleTx.xhtml" target="_blank" >
                            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{transaction.showSelectedTx(reference)}" value="#{c}" />
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Rartner">                               
                             #{c.pname}                                                                              
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Status">                                
                            #{c.fk_status}                                                   
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Sender">                                                 
                            #{c.sendername}                                 
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Beneficiary">                                   
                            #{c.beneficiaryname}                               
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Amounts">                            
                             #{c.beneficiary_currency} #{c.beneficiary_amount}                               
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Action">
                        <p:commandButton style="float:right" value="Print" >

                            <p:confirm header="#{cd.reference}" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" /> 
                            <p:button  value="Open" href="/faces/global/SingleTx.xhtml" target="_self" />

                        </p:commandButton>

                    </p:column>
                    <p:column style="width:32px">
                        <p:rowEditor />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                <p:dialog modal="true" width="800px" height="400px" widgetVar="singletx"
                          id="dialog">
                    Name :#{transaction.showSelectedTx(reference)}
                </p:dialog>

            </h:form>
```

**Here is the backing bean:**

```
package com.mycompany.data;

/**
 *
 * @author bryan
 */
import conn.DBConnector;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name = "transaction")
@SessionScoped
public class TransactionBean implements Serializable {

    //added
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public String reference;
    public String fk_status;
    public String sendername;
    public String beneficiaryname;
    public String beneficiary_currency;
    public double beneficiary_amount;
    public String pname;
    Transaction user;

    public String getReference() {
        return reference;
    }

    public void setReference(String reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    public String getFk_status() {
        return fk_status;
    }

    public void setFk_status(String fk_status) {
        this.fk_status = fk_status;
    }

    public String getSendername() {
        return sendername;
    }

    public void setSendername(String sendername) {
        this.sendername = sendername;
    }

    public String getBeneficiaryname() {
        return beneficiaryname;
    }

    public void setBeneficiaryname(String beneficiaryname) {
        this.beneficiaryname = beneficiaryname;
    }

    public String getBeneficiary_currency() {
        return beneficiary_currency;
    }

    public void setBeneficiary_currency(String beneficiary_currency) {
        this.beneficiary_currency = beneficiary_currency;
    }

    public double getBeneficiary_amount() {
        return beneficiary_amount;
    }

    public void setBeneficiary_amount(double beneficiary_amount) {
        this.beneficiary_amount = beneficiary_amount;
    }

    public String getPname() {
        return pname;
    }

    public void setPname(String pname) {
        this.pname = pname;
    }

    //resource injection
    @Resource(name = "jdbc/primefaces")

    //connect to DB and get customer list
    public List<Transaction> getTransactionList() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Connection con = null;

        con = DBConnector.getDBConnection();

        if (con == null) {
            throw new SQLException("Can't get database connection");
        }

        PreparedStatement ps
                = con.prepareStatement(
                        "select tx.reference,p.pname,ts.name, tx.sendername, tx.beneficiaryname, tx.beneficiary_currency,tx.beneficiary_amount from transaction_stage tx join transaction_status ts on tx.fk_status=ts.id join partner p on tx.fk_partner=p.id");

        //get customer data from database
        ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();

        List<Transaction> list = new ArrayList<Transaction>();

        while (result.next()) {
            Transaction cust = new Transaction();
            cust.setReference(result.getString("reference"));
            cust.setFk_status(result.getString("name"));
            cust.setSendername(result.getString("sendername"));
            cust.setBeneficiaryname(result.getString("beneficiaryname"));
            cust.setBeneficiary_currency(result.getString("beneficiary_currency"));
            cust.setBeneficiary_amount(result.getDouble("beneficiary_amount"));
            cust.setPname(result.getString("pname"));

            //store all data into a List
            list.add(cust);
        }

        return list;
        //added
    }

    //view single transaction
    private List<Transaction> selectSingleTx;

    public Transaction getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Transaction user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public List<Transaction> getSelectSingleTx() {
        return selectSingleTx;
    }

    public void setSelectSingleTx(List<Transaction> selectSingleTx) {
        this.selectSingleTx = selectSingleTx;
    }


    public  void showSelectedTx(String reference){
        Connection con=DBConnector.getDBConnection();
        if(con==null){
            System.out.println("No db connection");
        }
           String ref=getReference();
        try {
            String q="select tx.reference,p.pname,ts.name, tx.sendername, tx.beneficiaryname, tx.beneficiary_currency,tx.beneficiary_amount from transaction_stage tx join transaction_status ts on tx.fk_status=ts.id join partner p on tx.fk_partner=p.id where tx.reference="+ref+"";
            PreparedStatement ps=null;
            ResultSet rs=null;
            ps.setString(1, reference);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();

            display(rs);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    public void selectTx(String reference){

        showSelectedTx(reference);
    }

    // to be implemented later
    private static void display(ResultSet myRs) throws SQLException {
        while (myRs.next()) {
            String sendername = myRs.getString("sendername");
            String beneficiaryname = myRs.getString("beneficiaryname");
            //double salary = myRs.getDouble("salary");
            String department = myRs.getString("department");

            System.out.printf("%s, %s \n", sendername, beneficiaryname);
        }
    }

}
```

//

Comment: If you are new to all this, please try to find a better/newer tutorial. It is bad practice to do SQL in 'controller'/managed bean classes. It makes refactoring and re-using in e.g. an additional rest-api more difficult. (And that is not JSF's fault then). In addition, learn about things like JPA, with the advantage of bean validation and start using CDI `@Named` annotated classes instead of the JSF `@ManagedBean` And please learn to tag your questions better. It is not java-se, nor mysql, nor glassfish-4 related (tags are for where the problem is, not what you use)

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639785/jsf-controller-service-and-dao

Answer (score 1):

As per the `Reference` link, you need to include the value of c.reference in the link

```
 value="#{c.reference}"
```

See [JSF ViewParam from CommandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333187/jsf-viewparam-from-commandbutton)

or

[How to pass a parameter along with h:commandButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13048930/how-to-pass-a-parameter-along-with-hcommandbutton)

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12833918/parameter-passing-one-page-to-another-page-in-jsf-2-0 or...